# How to print char value in int array

Tags: c, arrays, arraylist

I have an array board[3][3] of type int. I want to show 8 numbers and on the last place "_" must be shown. I don't know how to do that. Please help

Comment: This is no tutoring site. See [ask] and show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 8 numbers you want print is the first 8, you can just use a loop to with `printf` to print it until the last number:

```
int j, k;
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        if (j == 2 && k == 2)
            printf("_");
        else
            printf("%d ", board[j][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. that worked

Comment: And if i want to print random numbers then what to do to place "_" at the end?

Comment: random numbers in the 3x3 board array?

Comment: yeah.. is it possible?

Comment: @user3837889 the code for print are all the same, it differs in how you assign the elements of the array, for example before it was `board[0][0]=1` not you can do `board[0][0] = rand()`;

Comment: All right.. thanks once again